# What rocket engine is this?

Tags: rockets, engines, identify-this-object

I came across [a meme](https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fxapwsaxavf461.jpg) depicting a supposedly oxygen rich, fuel rich, and "engine rich" cycle of rocket engine. However, I'm pretty sure at least one of them is incorrect listing what looks a lot like an RS-25 as "oxygen rich".  I'm curious if the the other one there is correct, specifically the "Fuel Rich" one, but I couldn't figure out which type of engine it is. I've cropped just the photo to the engine of interest here:

[image: Rocket engine firing vertically with orange-purple exhaust]

Can anyone identify which engine this is? At a minimum, we can rule out anything that's come out in the last 3 years

Comment: I ended up figuring this out purely by chance. After writing up my question (already having tried and failed to search), I threw the cropped image into Google's image search tool, and it immediately came up. I'm not sure why I didn't think of trying that earlier.

Comment: Makes sense that an image source would find it, those black panels on the nozzle are pretty unique.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yeah, I just wasn’t expecting success, since I usually only expect to be able to search for an exact match, rather than the original from a cropped or altered image.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this is a [RS-68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-68) engine, which is a hydrolox gas-generator cycle. I *think* it's a fuel-rich preburner gas-generator, at least. But it's at least not a form of staged combustion cycle like the other two from the meme.

[image: full photo of RS-68 engine from Wikipedia, from which the photo in the question was cropped]

Found here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RS-68_rocket_engine_test.jpg